# Where can I find this result that involves the reciprocal of the polynomial and its derivative?

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis, polynomials

I need to know in whick book I can see this result with the proof:

Let $Q(x)$ be a $n$-polynomial, which roots are $\{a_j\}_{j=1}^{n}$ and distinct. Then,
\begin{equation*}
 \dfrac{1}{Q(x)}=\sum_{j=1}^{n}\dfrac{1}{Q'(a_j)}\dfrac{1}{x-a_j}.
 \end{equation*}

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Are these roots distinct?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partial_fraction_decomposition#Procedure

Comment: Yes, the roots are distinct. Sorry, I forgot to write it.

Comment: Hint: $\;\frac{Q(x)}{x-a_j} \;\Big|_{\,x=a_j} = Q'(a_j)\,$.